# Use axis() to draw axis without ticks

Tags: r, plot, axis

Given a plot without axes, I would like to use `axis` to add a horizontal axis. On the left hand side you see the given "baseline" plot, on the right hand side the desired result:
[image: Baseline and expected plot]

The baseline plot is simply generated using

```
plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "Baseline")
```

**Question**: How to generated the desired output? (Condition: using `axis` after the plot has been generated.)

I expected that I get what I want when specifying `tick = FALSE, labels = FALSE`, but this doesn't work. Below my tests, hopefully self-explanatory:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "Full axis")
axis(1) # axis, ticks and labels

plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "No labels")
axis(1, labels = FALSE) # axis, ticks

plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "No ticks (and no axis)")
axis(1, tick = FALSE) # NO axis (unexpected), labels

plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "Nothing (instead of axis)")
axis(1, tick = FALSE, labels = FALSE) # nothing - expected: only axis without ticks, without labels
```

[image: Tests]

I expected the last plot to deliver the desired output, but the axis is not drawn at all. Apparently, `ticks = FALSE` suppresses the axis itself as well.

Remark: The "expected" plot was generated using

```
plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "Expected")
axis(1, at = c(-100, 100))
```

but I am looking for a "cleaner" solution than placing unwanted ticks outside the visible area.

Comment: box(which = "plot", lty = "solid")

Comment: other workarounds are `axis(1, lwd.tick=0, labels=FALSE)`, `axis(1, tcl=0, labels=FALSE)`, which draw 0 width or 0 length ticks, respectively.

Comment: @MartinMorgan: Thank you, works perfectly. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also read `?par`, specifically the parameters you can pass to "bty". 
box(which = "plot", lty ="solid", bty ="l"), Personally I would suggest this, as you get at least the axes. otherwise you got a plot with a floating 1 on a blank y axis

Comment: @infominer: I read `?par` and I know about `bty="l"` but instead of only a vertical axis this gives x and y axes. This is not what I need (because I need to draw the x axis using `axis()` in order to spefify its position using `pos`.) I didn't find a way to draw the vertical axis only using `bty`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other workarounds are `axis(1, lwd.tick=0, labels=FALSE)`, `axis(1, tcl=0, labels=FALSE)`, which draw 0 width or 0 length ticks, respectively. @LyzandeR's solution seems to draw white ticks on  top of the axis. The proposed `box()` solutions and `?par` don't seem to draw just the X axis?

Comment: I like this one more tbh. Printing ticks in white is acceptable but leaves these hard-to-notice-but-still-there white marks on the axis. So, this is better.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to plot what you want:

```
plot(1, axes = FALSE, main = "No labels")
axis(1, label=F, col.ticks='white') # axis, ticks
```

It just prints the ticks as white:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I prefer @Martin Morgan's solution because it is more general (doesn't rely on white background).

Comment: You re welcome :). It is the annoying white marks on the line that bother me. If you specify a background colour it would be easy to add that as the colour for the ticks as well (in my opinion).

Comment: Of course - but still, adjusting the tick color to the background color is a "dependency" you always have to keep in mind while ticks of width 0 work in every setting.